# How to cart an order in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My application is an on line order taking application.

I want to know what is the right approach to cart the items. Although I am using session this way.

I created a separate `sessionManaging` class and there I have properties that will hold the session like this:

```
public static List<custHeader> currOrderItemCustomizationSession
{
      get
      {
         if (HttpContext.Current.Session["currOrderItemCustomization"] != null)
            return ((List<custHeader>)HttpContext.Current.Session["currOrder"]);
         else
            HttpContext.Current.Session["currOrderItemCustomization"] = 
                                                         new List<custHeader>();    
         return (List<custHeader>)
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["currOrderItemCustomization"];
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["currOrderItemCustomization"] = value;
        }
    }
```

There are other properties also like `currOrder`, `currOrderItem`, `currOrderItemCustomization` and I applied the same way session idea to them too.

But when I set session and try to access in controller it always null.

```
public ActionResult GetProductCustomization(int pId)
{
    List<custHeader> custHeader =
                      reposCustomization.GetHeaderCustomization(pId);
     cOrderSession.currOrderItemCustomizationSession = custHeader; 
     return PartialView("_customization", custHeader);
}
```

Here when I check it with break point I find  `cOrderSession.currOrderItemCustomizationSession` this is null always.

Comment: Stating the obvious but : Are you sure `reposCustomization.GetHeaderCustomization(pId)` doesn't return a null.

Comment: Also, please ensure you spelling correctly next time, it will get more people to read and therefore answer your question. Try also to make sure your code doesn't span the width of the post (so no horizontal scrollbars appear in your code block) It makes it less painful to read.

Comment: OK, i will but at least let me know is it a right approach to maintain the session and will i be able to get at other place it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in my code itself

```
return ((List<custHeader>)HttpContext.Current.Session["currOrder"]);
```

is suppose to be

```
return ((List<custHeader>)HttpContext.Current.Session["currOrderItemCustomization"]);
```